# Why does this Verilog module show "invalid module item" on the 9th line?

Tags: verilog, clock, digital, edaplayground

I was learning about loops in Verilog and wanted to create a simple clock with time period of 20ns. I am getting the error below whenever I am trying to run the code in EDA Playground.

```
module Pulse(clock);
  output reg clock;
  
  initial
    begin
      clock = 1'b0;
    end
  
  forever #10 clock = ~clock;      //Error is here
endmodule
```

design.sv:9: syntax error
design.sv:9: error: invalid module item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forever` cannot be used outside of a procedural block. It will work if you put it the initial block:

```
initial
   begin
      clock = 1'b0;
      forever #10 clock = ~clock;  
   end
```

Answer (score 3):

`forever` is a procedural statement; it does not create a process like `initial` or `always` . You can put the `forever` inside the `initial` block` or just write

```
 always #10 clk = ! clk;
```